# How to create a cancelled task

Tags: task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0, cancellation-token

I am writing a Stream class and am blocked in the ReadAsync method. Please take a look at the code, I think it can explain the situation better that I can do it with my English.

```
public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return _connection.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, offset, count));
    }
    return // <---------------    what here?
}
```

Using ILSpy I can see that other Stream classes return a cancelled task as follow:

```
return new Task<TResult>(true, default(TResult), TaskCreationOptions.None, cancellationToken);
```

However that Task's constructor is internal and I cannot invoke it.

Google didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most direct way I know to create a canceled task is to use a `TaskCompletionSource`:

```cs
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
tcs.TrySetCanceled();
return tcs.Task;
```

If you haven't used it before, `TaskCompletionSource` provides a "promise-style" task, which basically allows you to say, "Here, take this `Task` now, and I'll provide the result (or report an error/cancellation) whenever I'm ready."  It's useful when you want to schedule/coordinate work yourself, as opposed to simply relying on a `TaskScheduler`.

Alternatively, if you rewrite your method using `async/await`, you can force the cancellation exception to automatically propagate to the result `Task`:

```cs
public async override Task<int> ReadAsync(
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int count,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    return await _connection.ReceiveAsync(
        new ArraySegment<byte>(
            buffer,
            offset,
            count));
}
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` because of the necessary runtime expense of throwing an exception and unwinding the stack - when I could just do `if( token.IsCancelationRequested ) return Task.FromCanceled( token )` but how do I do that in an `async` method?

Comment: @Dai You can't; once you mark the method as `async Task<T>`, you must return a `T`.  I wouldn't worry about the overhead of throwing the exception.  Optimize for the common case.  Cancellation should be uncommon.  This is the idiomatic way to propagate cancellation within an `async` method.

Answer (score 16):

The [next version of .Net (v4.5.3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/10/06/announcing-october-2014-updates-to-net-framework-vnext-asp-net-vnext-and-net-native-in-visual-studio-14-ctp4.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) is adding a way to create a cancelled task leveraging that internal constructor. There are both a generic and non-generic versions:

```cs
var token = new CancellationToken(true);
Task task = Task.FromCanceled(token);
Task<int> genericTask = Task.FromCanceled<int>(token);
```

Keep in mind that the `CancellationToken` being used must be canceled before calling `FromCanceled`